# How to expand RecyclerView to full screen on touching item of it?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have some `RecyclerView` that located on bottom of screen and below of other views. Currently,it is horizontally and only 1 row. I want to expand it to full screen for better view,when user touches on some item. And on expanding it has to have 2 columns. Also user can go back by clicking back button on menu that appears after expanding is done.

What did I do? 
I've found `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` for that. It allows change amount of columns. 
What is my problem? I couldn't determine do I have to use another activity for that. But I guess it is redundant. How can I achieve this in one activity? What to do with other view that are above of `RecyclerView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you're looking for, and without being more specific, a BottomSheet may be the solution. See here: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-bottom-sheets-with-the-design-support-library--cms-26031

Alternatively, you may use a `FrameLayout` to contain your `RecyclerView` and another layout containing all your other Views. Set `RecyclerView` gravity to `bottom` and give it the height of your row (in the example 80dp). Notice that `RecyclerView` is the last element, so it draws on top of the other elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- other views here -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Mark your answer after this a little hint. I've learned how to use `bottomsheet`, but how to hide all things(that are located below my recyclerview)  under `bottomsheet` when expanding was done? By using FrameLayout?

Comment: `BottomSheet` as implemented by the Design Library should take care of it. `FrameLayout` on the other hand is a way to layout views which can overlap (`RelativeLayout` also allows overlap, while `LinearLayout` doesn't). The important bit in that case is that the element you want to be on top is the last one i.e. drawing is done in the same order the views are in the layout, in my example `LinearLayout`is drawn first, then `RecyclerView`, and they overlap because the parent is a `FrameLayout`. Hope this clears things up.